# Count number of different occurrences in a cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, rasterization

I have points that correspond to the observation of different species. These point are grouped in taxonomic orders (for those not familiar with the term, just imagine that a few hundred species are aggregated into a dozen or so groups). I want to make a raster in which the value of the cells corresponds to the number of different orders in each cell. I've tried spatial join and a few different things, but I haven't managed thus far.

Comment: For me it is unclear what data you have. For example you cant spatial join Points to a raster. Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly there are some easy ways to do this, depending on what sort of technology is available to you(arc licencing is stupid and confusing and you might need a spatial analysis licence to do this, but other programs can do this too I think. 90% sure qgis could do this). Most GIS programs can create a fishnet(a grid). You could:

- generate this fishnet for the area you wish the raster to represent.
- Add column(s) for the point count(s)
- You can then do a spatial join with the points to get sum of points into each of those cells.
- It sounds a little like you could end up with a cell that has 2 cats 1 dog and 3 deer points and that you want the raster to represent that as a 3 species cell? If that's the case you repeat the spatial join for each of the point classes you have and use field calculator on an additional column with some basic logic that says sum number of columns that are above zero for that cell.
- This fishnet is then easy to turn into a raster with the raster cells band value(s) simply being based on the value column(s) of the fishnet.